# grep match distinguish between 1 and -1

Tags: regex, grep, match

Let's say I have a following:

```
>>tmp='1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1'
>>echo $tmp
1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

And I use the commands:

```
>>echo $tmp | grep -ow 1 | wc -l
10
>>echo $tmp | grep -ow "\-1" | wc -l
5
```

How am I able to get *just* the counts of 1 (which the answer should be 5 given the example above) without including the negative 1's?

Comment: You need to tell us more about the input string. Will it only contain the tokens `1` and `-1`, separated by whitespace? If not, what else is possible? Could you, for example, have tokens like `a1`, or `1.5`? If they are possible, what exactly do you need to count?

Comment: What about the solution below? Does it work?

Comment: the solution works as needed. As for the comment by mathguy, I would have specified if there were other separators that were necessary. Since I didn't include it in my original post, it should be assumed that the information wasn't pertinent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
echo "$temp" | grep -oE '(^|[^-0-9])1\b' | wc -l
```

Or, if the numbers are separated with whitespace, use **whitespace boundaries** you may use a PCRE regex with a GNU grep, or a Perl equivalent:

```
echo "$temp" | grep -oP '(?<!\S)1(?!\S)' | wc -l
perl -lne 'END {print $c} map ++$c, /(?<!\S)1(?!\S)/g'
```

See the [online demo #1](https://ideone.com/1OrMMz) and [online demo #2](https://ideone.com/vb6Zcy).

**Details**

- `-o` - output matches only
- `-E` - enable POSIX ERE syntax
- `-P` - enables PCRE syntax
- `(^|[^-0-9])` - matches start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a char other than `-` and a digit
- `(?<!\S)`  - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `1` - a `1` digit
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\S)`  - right-hand whitespace boundary

Comment: Alas this is not very robust; for example it will count 1.5 in the input `1 1 -1 1.5 3 -2.3` This shows why it is important to get all the necessary clarification from the OP first. (Very often posters won't think about such issues until they get an answer, they take it back to their real-life problem and they find out that it doesn't work.)

Comment: @mathguy OP posted an `awk` question related to the same subject, so I believe the boundaries are whitespaces here, I also posted an answer there and here, I believe, `grep -oP '(?<!\S)1(?!\S)'` will do. If  GNU `grep`  is not available, it can be done with Perl, `perl -lne 'END {print $c} map ++$c, /(?<!\S)1(?!\S)/g'`.

Comment: If indeed whitespace is the separator, something like this should work: `grep -oP '(\s|^)1(?=(\s)|$)'`.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, but alternation in capturing groups will cause more backtracking than simple lookarounds with single-char patterns.